# Error converting odt to java with odftoolkit

Tags: java, pdf, odt, odftoolkit

This is my first time with odftoolkit and I'm having an extrange error. I have an .odt template and when converting to pdf it looses data.

Example:

```
    **Title 1:**
Text 1.
    **Title 2:**
Text 2.
```

The thing is that cnverted PDF only have Text1 / text2 and nothin about the titles. Both are the same font but different heigth.

```
public static File convertir(File informe) throws Exception{
    logger.entry();
    File informePdf = null;
    String filePath = "";
    try{
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(informe);
        filePath = informe.getAbsolutePath().replace(".ODT",".PDF");
        informePdf = new File(filePath);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(informePdf);
        ConversorPDF conversor = new ConversorPDF(is, os, false, true);
        conversor.convert();
        logger.trace("Convertido a PDF correctamente");
        return informePdf;
    }catch ( Exception e){
        logger.catching(e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Please show us your code, otherwise we can't tell you where the error is and how to fix it

Comment: Edited. I've passed 3 .odts and works with two but there is one that does not work. It says "Convertido a PDF correctamente" but the PDF is incorrect

Comment: Error localized. The error was that in libreOffice this text was "list parameter" font type and not "Predeterminated Style". Hope it helps someone.